# How can I clean up lines, drawn by a FMX TScrollBox Bug, outside of TScrollBox?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In my main application I'm experiencing a bug with FMX TScrollBox. While scrolling down in the scrollbox, the TNumberbox leaves behind lines in other components. Even after repainting/updating the other components (with the lines) the lines aren't cleaned up.

To clarify I made a dummy application:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3TdI.jpg)

[Component breakdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoS4K.png)

I understand that there's probably no way to get rid of the bug. However I would like to know how I can clean up the lines in my application. Anyone that can help?

Comment: no sure if it's will help, but could you try the TALScrollBox (better talVertScrollBox) that you can found at https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe ? it's have the same properties of TscrollBox (so the change must be easy) but it's implementation is a little different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug appears when using TGridpanelLayout in a TScrollBox (any kind). To avoid this you avoid using TGridpanelLayout directly in a TScrollbox.

You can do this by using standard TLayouts in the TScrollbox, or using a frame with TGridpanelLayout in it.

Comment: To add to this; don't use TScrollBox with TFrames with TGridpanelLayout in them with more than 1 row. It will randomly reset align/text size/ text align etc.